# Web page delivers two different sets of output when scraped vs viewed

Tags: c#, .net, web-scraping, webrequest

I'm trying to scrape a web page hosted on a device on my network.  I've done this dozens of times with other model devices on the same network.  When I browse to the page in IE or Chrome, it's formatted properly and I see the source I'm expecting.

However, when I try to read the response stream in .Net or try running it in Fiddler, I'm given source for what looks like Javascript and session generating scripting rather than the numbers I care about.

I think this page is now hitting a javascript powered landing page, calling back to the printer, then formatting and outputting back into my browser.  I think my difference is that calls from inside of Fiddler and .Net GetResponseStream() calls aren't letting the javascript do what it needs to to get all of the data.

Sample

```
            WebRequest ConReq = WebRequest.Create(consumablePage);
            WebRequest UseReq = WebRequest.Create(usagePage);
            ConReq.Timeout = 15000;
            UseReq.Timeout = 20000;
            WebResponse ConResp = ConReq.GetResponse();
            WebResponse UseResp = UseReq.GetResponse();

            Stream Constream = ConResp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader Consr = new StreamReader(Constream);

            Stream Usestream = UseResp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader Usesr = new StreamReader(Usestream);

            string conRead = Consr.ReadToEnd();
            string useRead = Usesr.ReadToEnd();
```

At the end, conRead and useRead both contain:

```
"<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<script language=\"JavaScript\" type=\"text/javascript\">\r\n<!-- \r\nfunction SetCookie ( inCookieName, inCookieValue, inCookieExpiration)\r\n{\r\n\tdocument.cookie\t\t= inCookieName + \"=\" + escape( inCookieValue ) + \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t( inCookieExpiration ? \"; expires=\" + getExpiryDate(inCookieExpiration) : \"\" ) + \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\"; path=/\";\r\n}\r\n\r\nfunction getExpiryDate(nodays)\r\n{\r\n\tvar UTCstring;\r\n\tToday = new Date();\r\n\tnomilli=Date.parse(Today);\r\n\tToday.setTime(nomilli+nodays*24*60*60*1000);\r\n\tUTCstring = Today.toUTCString();\r\n\treturn UTCstring;\r\n}\r\n\r\nfunction generateSessionID()\r\n{\r\n\tvar \tgetTcpIpAddr = \"10.210.13.138\";\r\n\tvar  SESSION_ID =\"SESSION_ID\";\r\n\tvar ipArray = getTcpIpAddr.split(\".\");\r\n\tvar ip = parseInt(ipArray[0], 10) + parseInt(ipArray[1], 10) + parseInt(ipArray[2], 10) + parseInt(ipArray[3], 10);\r\n\tvar d = new Date();\r\n\tID = parseInt((d.getMilliseconds()*ip)/32, 10);\r\n\tSetCookie(SESSION_ID, ID,365);\t//365 - expiry date is 1 year\r\n\twindow.location=window.location.toString();\r\n}\r\n-->\r\n</script>\r\n</head>\r\n<body onLoad=\"generateSessionID()\">\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
```

This picture is an example of a Fiddler GET, and an IE instance of the same page.  Note the Fiddler response is only 1075K and the IE response is 6602K.

[image: Example GETs]

How can I get a fully parsed response stream back in .Net?

Comment: It's not my code.  It's Fiddler output for the page access.  My code is in the code blocks above it.

Comment: The `GetResponseStream()` method will not evaluate any javascript, it will only get the raw contents of the page. When the page is using javascript to display its data, and you want to scrape that data, then AFAIK you'll either have to use a complete `WebBrowser` control or somehow evaluate the javascript yourself (which is probably not an easy task).

Comment: Haven't really worked with WebBrowser before but I'll give it a shot.  You're probably right.